# From array of dictionaries, make array containing values of one key

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionaries. I would like to extract an array with all the elements of one particular key of the dictionaries in the original array. Can this be done without enumeration?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, use the [NSArray `-valueForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ) method.

```
NSArray *extracted = [sourceArray valueForKey:@"a key"];
```

Comment: @e.James, you learn if you ask and your curious. I came up with the thought about how to implement this, because i didn't want to loop around and do like the old-school style. I'm glad I looked for a way of doing that, and like you say, learnt another new thing, cheers for learning everyday! :)

Comment: Can we do this for a set of keys, or is it available for only one key?

Comment: This kind of method available in `Swift`?

Comment: @user3589771 check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367261/key-value-coding-kvc-with-array-dictionary-in-swift for some possible solutions in Swift

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, [Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26367532/3589771) not works for me. Finally, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30693198/3589771). I tried if swift provide single line like obj-c.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, just use Key-Value Coding to ask for the values of the key:

```
NSArray* names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"Joe",@"firstname",
                   @"Bloggs",@"surname",
                   nil],
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"Simon",@"firstname",
                   @"Templar",@"surname",
                   nil],
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"Amelia",@"firstname",
                   @"Pond",@"surname",
                   nil],
                  nil];

//use KVC to get the names
NSArray* firstNames = [names valueForKey:@"firstname"];

NSLog(@"first names: %@",firstNames);
```