# Query plist that is an array of dictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a plist that has an array of dicts. in the dict there is a KEY with the name UID. I want to query the plist where UID="1234" .. how would I search?

sample

```
<array>
   <dict>
      <key>UID</key>
      <string>1234</string>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>bob</string>
   </dict>
   ....
</array>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array from Array with dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680403/array-from-array-with-dictionaries)

Comment: @DavidGelhar: Perhaps not; it seems like @magic-c0d3r wants to *filter* the array, not extract values from each object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read in the plist as an array of dictionaries and then use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method on `NSArray`:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyInfo" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *plistData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UID = %d", 1234];
NSArray *filtered = [plistData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
NSLog(@"found matches: %@", filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read in the plist as an array of dictionaries and then use the objectForKey: method of NSDictionary.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyInfo" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *plistData = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] retain];
for (NSDictionary *dict in plistData) {
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"UID"] isEqualToString:@"1234"]) {
        NSLog(@"Found it!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid a for loop if possible. That is what I am doing now.  I was wondering if there was an alternative.

Comment: See Dave DeLong's answer above! His solution should work just fine.