# Key-Value Coding (KVC) with Array/Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, key-value-coding

Is it possible to key-value code (KVC) with native Swift data structures such as Array and Dictionary? Key-Value coding is still available for NSFoundation structures within Swift, just like in Objective C.

For example, this is valid:

```
var nsarray: NSArray = NSArray()
// Fill the array with objects
var array: NSArray = nsarray.valueForKeyPath("key.path")
```

But this is invalid:

```
var swiftarray: Array = []
// Fill the array with objects
var array = swiftarray.valueForKeyPath("key.path") // Invalid, produces a compile-time error
```

Comment: do you mean `swiftarray` at the last line of code?

Comment: Check out this post by Matt Long: http://www.cimgf.com/2014/11/05/swift-and-valueforkeypath-you-cant-keep-a-good-api-down/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that KVC on native Swift objects is just not supported. Here's the most elegant workaround I've found:

```
var swiftarray: Array = []
// Fill the array with objects
var array: NSArray = (swiftarray as NSArray).valueForKeyPath("key.path") as NSArray
```

Answer (score 8):

I've found this:

```
var array = swiftarray.map({$0["key.path"]! as ObjectType})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do the following:

```
let items : Array<String> = (myArray as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("name") as! Array<String>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
let names = array.map { $0.name }
```

Instead of using key paths you can directly refer to property or method.