# How to write array.valueForKey in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

What's the most convenient code to write

```
[results valueForKey:@"attribute"]
```

in swift?
I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367261/key-value-coding-kvc-with-array-dictionary-in-swift) that it's recommended to use the map() function with a closure:

```
swiftarray.map({$0["attribute"]})
```

N.B. swiftarray is not a NSArray

Comment: For some reason my computer has decided it no longer wants to run any Swift code (useful...) but I'm pretty sure you can run this and just remove the parentheses from it? I think possibly both ways are valid though. Have you tried this in a playground? TBH, I can't see how the error you are getting is related to the code you have posted? Is it definitely from it?

Comment: Could you post the entire use case? What type is your array?

Comment: @Fogmeister "my computer has decided it no longer wants to run any Swift code" Wow, I think I'd like to hear more about _that_!

Comment: @matt no idea how it happened or how to fix it :( I suspect it would involve reinstalling OSX. But yeah, playgrounds just sit there with the spinner but not executing any code and projects don't compile. Can't remember the error though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'am not sure but if you have some object in array other than Dictionary (or other type that supports subscripting), you will need to use following code

```
results.map({$0.attribute})
```

Comment: I actually get the error message: "AnyObject" has no member "attribute-name"

Comment: Then you need to cast you AnyObject to the real object type that contains in your results array

Comment: Which means I cannot use the concise closure you wrote in your answer, because I need to specify the type of the parameter in the signature of the closure.

Comment: You can  cast you results array to array of your actual object type before this mapping and the use this closure. Something like that `if let actualResult = result as? [MyClass] {
    actualResult.map {$0.attribute}
}`

Comment: Or less safe `(result as! [MyClass]).map {$0.attribute}`

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to do this in swift 4.2

Answer (score 0):

> What's the most convenient code to write
>
> ```
> [results valueForKey:@"attribute"]
> ```
>
> in swift?

That would be:

```
  results.valueForKey("attribute")
```

Comment: For an array of custom objects, I get the error `Value of type '[TestObject]' has no member 'valueForKey'`

Comment: @JamesWebster Obviously the object to which you send `valueForKey` would need to be a class derived from NSObject, because that's where `valueForKey` lives. If you've got an array, it needs to be an NSArray, and its elements need to be NSObject derivatives. But that is not what the OP asked (as far as I can tell)... Or is it?

Comment: @Matt Why do you assume that the array is a derived from NSObject? This is a swift array, not a NSArray. I also get the message has no member 'valueForKey'. Otherwise the question would be a really stupid one.

Comment: @Biclops No, but the OP asked the wrong question. I answered the wrong-headed question that the OP asked. After all, if Objective-C `valueForKey:` works on a particular NSArray of a particular kind of object, Swift `value(forKey:)` will work perfectly well on an NSArray of that same kind of object.

Answer (score 0):

Does your class have a subscript?

I've been able to create a test class which can use the KVC accessors like so:

```
class TestObject
{
    var name:String
    var numbers:[String:Int] = [String:Int]()

    init(name:String)
    {
        self.name = name
    }

    subscript(index: String) -> Int? {
        get {
            return numbers[index]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            numbers[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with the following code:

```
let testObject1 = TestObject(name: "test1")
testObject1["home-phone"] = 1234
testObject1["mobile-phone"] = 5678

let testObject2 = TestObject(name: "test2")
testObject2["office"] = 0987
testObject2["mobile-phone"] = 6543

let array : [TestObject] = [testObject1, testObject2]

var results = array.map({$0["office"]})
print("Results:\(results)")

results = array.map({$0["mobile-phone"]})
print("Results:\(results)")
```

produces the following result:

```
Results:[nil, Optional(987)]
Results:[Optional(5678), Optional(6543)]
```